# NiFi: Unable to read expression language variables from external properties files

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to externalize the hard coded values into a properties file and use expression language syntax in my nifi workflows.

I have updated the nifi.properties with the following

```
nifi.variable.registry.properties=/opt/nifi/config/nifi_variables_dev.properties
```

And one of the entry in the prop file is

```
zookeeper.url=192.168.134.120:2181
```

And when i used the expression language syntax ${zookeeper.url}

And i am not seeing any error ( exclamation icon on the processor). Also is there a way to check what value does an expression evaluates to in Nifi.

By the way i am using nifi version 1.4.0.

and in the logs i am seeing the following error:

```
Directory '' does not have sufficient permissions (i.e., not writable and readable); rolling back session: {}java.lang.IllegalStateException: Directory '' does not have sufficient permissions (i.e., not writable and readable)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart NiFi after setting `nifi.variable.registry.properties` in `nifi.properties`?

Comment: Yes i restarted nifi.

Comment: where did you use  expression `${zookeeper.url}` ?

Comment: I have a GetFile Processor and for the Input Path i used ${input_path} and input_path is added to the properties file. Sorry zookeeper.url is used in some other processor.

Comment: it should work as you described. try your new property in `UpdateAttribute` processor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like variable registry is not supported in 1.4.0 !! We switched to nifi 1.5.0 and everything is working as expected.